# Apache Tomcat doesnt work through IntelliJ but works when launched manually

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Im trying to test simple "hello" app using Spring and Tomcat. Im able to start Apache Tomcat manually on *localhost:8080* and I successfully get to Apache site that says its configured properly. However when I try to launch my app through IntelliJ, I dont get any errors, on *localhost:8080/sayHello* I get *Message The requested resource [/sayHello] is not available*.

This is my config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("app")
public class Config extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

This my only one controller:

```
@RestController
public class Hello {

    @GetMapping("/sayHello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Here is pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I hoped I didnt miss anything. If so, please remind me. Its my first contact with Spring and Tomcat.

Comment: Maybe missing mapping in web.xml file. Can you add it's content?

Comment: I dont see this file in my project at all. I read its supposed to be in /WEB-INF but I have there only 2 subfolders: /classes and /lib.

EDIT: Also I read that I can generate it manually but its better not to if Im using annotations instead of xml.

Comment: I believe the file is supposed to be there even when using annotations.